# Best way to check SVN revision changes of directory and return if changes are found

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn

I have been looking for a while now about how to check the revision and return if there has been changes. What I have works but I am wondering if there is a better/ cleaner way:

```
bool needToUpdate = false;
Process process = new Process();
var info = new ProcessStartInfo("svn", string.Format(@"status -u {0}", directoryInto.FullName));
process.StartInfo = info;
process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
    {
        string data = e.Data;
        //This if statement is what I have an issue with.
        if (data.Contains("!"))
            needToUpdate = true;
    }
});
```

As you can see I am checking the string to find a (!) in the string. Its not great practice, so I am seeing if anyone would be able to help me out with a better solution or a better way to receive the standard output from the SVN **(I am not asking how to do it, I am asking a better way than I already have)** I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

> **EDIT** Using SharpSVN

---

I am now using SharpSVN and I having a problem with IsRemoteUpdate, it seems to always be returning true:

```
bool needToUpdate = false;
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    SvnStatusArgs statusArgs = new SvnStatusArgs();
    statusArgs.RetrieveAllEntries = true;
    statusArgs.RetrieveRemoteStatus = true;
    client.GetStatus(directoryInto.FullName, statusArgs, out statuses);
    for (int i = 0; i < statuses.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (statuses[i].IsRemoteUpdated)
        {
            needToUpdate = true;
            break;
        }  
    }
}
```

Could you tell me why this is always returning true, even when my directory is updated?

> Edit #2
>   I have since added:

```
if (statuses[i].LocalContentStatus == SvnStatus.Missing || statuses[i].LocalContentStatus == SvnStatus.Modified)
```

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Rather than introduce an external dependency (`svn.exe`) and incur the overhead of spawning an external process, use [SharpSVN](https://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) which provides support for SVN via a library.

Comment: If you stick with `svn.exe`, try the XML output to parse more deterministically.

Comment: @alroc Since we already have tortoise installed on the machines I believe it's better to use it rather than getting another install that everyone is going to have to get. Pressed enter too soon, Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Your users won't need to install anything - you build SharpSVN into your application. There's even a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=SharpSvn) for it.

Comment: If I am just checking for updates on one folder (every min)  is SharpSVN what I am looking for?

Comment: Yes, that would be preferable over spawning a new process every minute.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will check it out.

Comment: @alroc I have updated my question to a Sharp SVN question.

Answer (score -1):

There is a discussion on the SharpSVN forum about this: [How to check if working copy is latest version?](https://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=728&dsMessageId=360934) There they use similar solution, like you: get status, iterate through items, if any has `IsRemoteUpdated`, the SVN directory needs to be updated.